# iOS Subscription Management

Tags: ios, cross-platform, subscription

I have a question regarding subscription management under ios.
The app i am developing needs a login with username & password. 
The same login is also available on a website and an android application.

The subscription needs to be available on every platform for the logged in app-user, but should not be available for other users logging in on the same device.

Is it possible to implement subscription management that way under ios?
So that the subscription is connected to the logged in app-user instead of the apple id?

------------- edit 1 --------------------

i am talking about in app purchases (Auto-renewable subscriptions)

----------------edit 2 ----------------------

i found that there is a SkMutablePayment class with an applicationUsername Property. But if i use the restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername method it does not seem to work properly. Can anybody provide a sample on how to use it? Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about subscription for push notifications?

Comment: i am talking about in app purchases (Auto-renewable subscriptions)

Comment: ok, so answer is no. Also I don't think it's possible on Android. Not by built-in means. You have to develop your own payment system. And read Apple's guidelines carefully to prevent rejection.

Comment: i found that there is a SkMutablePayment class with an applicationUsername Property. But if i use the restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername method it does not seem to work properly. Can anybody provide a sample on how to use it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Roland85. You have to provide your own association at the backend side to the logged-in user, your server can match the receipt from Apple to the current logged in user, Guidelines tell you to have to provide it across all user devices (where your app is available), so you are allowed to tie it to 1 user in particular.